# How can I get command line arguments from java equinox bundle?

Tags: java, osgi

I've an equinox application and I want get some eventual command line parameters that the user can use. How can I get these parameters?

Comment: You want to list the arguments that were used to start equinox or list the possible arguments that the user can use?

Comment: I would take the possible arguments that user can use @BalazsZsoldos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of possible arguments are listed in the EclipseLauncher class as constants. If you want, you can get the constants of the class with reflection. System property names are prefixed with "PROP_".
This might work for one version, but not for other. I would not recommend this.

You can get the system properties via System.getProperties() (I guess this was trivial).

If you want to now if the arguments have been passed in Oracle based JVM with the *sun.java.command* system property. This will not work with other JVM implementations.

Non of the options above are suggested to use in production :). I would be interested in the use-case you want to implement by getting these arguments programmatically.

Comment: Basically it's a bundle that manage(send, receive) zigbee events. When the package is launched it's possible run it with some options(e.g. enable debug log). Now my main task is transform this package in an OSGi bundle(doesn't matter the distribution). My main problem is transform the static void and I don't know how to do. Anyway thanks for your answer